# Improve the view of one long cell with RadGridView

Tags: wpf, telerik-grid, radgridview

It has a RadGridView (WEB WPF Application) the corresponding data set including an identifier and a description that usually is so long that it not is clearly legible in the row.

How to modify the grid so that when having a selected row that can be "expanded" or shown on multiple lines to make it more readable?

Answer (score 2):

Try making a DataTemplate contaning a TextBlock with text wrapping to display your data.

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ExpedibleCellTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap">
        </DataTemplate>
```

Then in your RadGridView set the appropriate Column's data Template

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource ExpedibleCellTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: I have a question....I dont use a GridViewDataColumn at the explicit way. I assign data to GridView across a Dataset....from a Query, SQL procedure, etc.....In that context how I can apply this.....